# How to change the color of only one elemet and move only one element to right side?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active home_button" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Results</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.navbar {
  height: 73px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #362890;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
```

I want to do two things. Firstly I want to make the color of Home orange. Secondly, I want to move About Us on the right side while keeping others on the left side. How can I do that?

Comment: `li:last-child{float:right;}`, but you can also use flex and forget about float for that kind of layout nowdays ... `a[href="#home"]{color:oange;}` Also look at selector specifity to make sure it works :)

Comment: I am not able to change the colour of "Home" otherwise float property is working fine. I see ".navbar li a" is overwriting the color of Home to white. although I'am calling by the class "home-button" then also it is not working.

Comment: .. you did not look for specifity : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity that's parts of the basics to know. :)

Comment: Thank you @G-Cyrillus :) That was something I had missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float:right` for the About Us item, and `color:orange` for the Home item.

```css
.navbar {
  height: 73px;
  width: 100%;
}


.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #362890;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.home_button{
  color:orange !important;
}
#about-us{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active home_button" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Results</a></li>
    <li id="about-us"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The about us is working but the color of "Home" isn't changing. But if I remove the color from " .navbar li a " then it is working. Please help

Comment: @Pritam read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity you should find out by yourself how to overide styles ..

Comment: Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets -- I found this from the post you have given to me. That is why I seriously want to find an alternate method of doing it, without using the !important property

Answer (score 1):

I think adding a
 `!important` to `.home_button` should do the trick, give it a try...
Example

```
.home_button {
  color: orange !important;
}
```

The !important property in CSS is used to provide more weight (importance) than normal property. In CSS, the !important means that “this is important”, ignore all the subsequent rules, and apply !important rule
For more info on how !important works  [check here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-important-in-css/)

Answer (score -1):

give home and about a class, then style it